# Can't save data to database

Tags: database, row, mdf

I'm creating my first database via c# and visual studio 2k12. I added new item, went throw all those setups and finally saw *.mdf. Then I added new table, added data and by drag&drop added components to form. Since here everything goes right. But then I made a button, which add new row to database. In datagridview seems everything okay, new row appeared. Then i closed window and made a look at database if everything is okay. Then I saw that database is disconnected and data nowhere. I use this code to add new raw.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Database1DataSet.MP3Row newMP3Row = database1DataSet.MP3.NewMP3Row();
        newMP3Row.path = "D://new/mp3";
        this.database1DataSet.MP3.Rows.Add(newMP3Row);
        this.mP3TableAdapter.Update(this.database1DataSet.MP3);
    }
```

Could someone tell me, where i made a mistake?

Answer (score 3):

Finally I finished this problem. My code is corect, but there was problem with database. I found documentm, which helped me solve my problem. Here is link, point 2: [FAQ: My database isn't being updated, but no errors occurred in my application](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/ad837d14-31ea-445f-b830-1a8682b69e68)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need a database1DataSet.Commit() or database1DataSet.SaveChanges()

VS2012 will show you all options available there ;)

Comment: If you need more help just update your post and most likely I will get a notification about it.

Comment: So I tried that, what you recommanded, but there is nothing like that. I just found  this.database1DataSet.MP3.AcceptChanges(); but there's the same result :-( I see problem that when i close that program, database is disconected and when i have opened inserted data table and click on update, I get error "This database cannot be imported. It is either an unsipported SQL Server version of an unsupported database compatibility". Maybe it's something little, like one line, but I'm new on that and i really don't know if I do it right, but seems like I did.